# Building for multiple screen sizes without size classes

Tags: ios, autolayout, fullscreen, size-classes, uistackview

I am currently writing an iPhone app (my first one) and never used

```
Size Classes 
Auto Layout  
Stack Views
```

To set the views/images/labels etc. on the screen. didn't use storyboard as well,
Every thing that is shown is coded.

I didn't start using these tools because back at the time (a couple of months ago) they seemed to be more of a pain than a true gain for my development process,
But looking back i feel i made a mistake and now I'm way too deep in code to start it all over again with the traditional/designated tools.

So, Having said that, are there any known frameworks and/or best practices to make sure that all that's printed are scaled  exactly the same and have relevant ratio for each device size?

Something like: calculating the height/width ratio and somehow applying it to all the views/images etc?

is there any good way to get out of this mess?

Comment: Well you probably don't want every element to scale according to main screen width / height, some things would be huge on iPads and way too small on phones like 5s.. Even in interface builder, you generally wouldn't do that. That being said, Snapkit is a great tool for programmatically creating constraints. If you want some things to scale, you're going to have to calculate percentages according to viewport width / height.

Comment: If every device is going to have the same layout with different sizes of elements, then it is definitely worth your time to learn/use auto layout.

Comment: The way out is to learn Interface Builder and all it's functionality (including Size Classes, Autolayout and Stack Views plus more). There are many advantages to Interface Builder including `1)` No more code->compile->check->code cycle as you can see the interface live at design time for multiple devices. `2)` Many less lines of code in your app to maintain `3)` It is simply easier to change and update a UI in IB than if the UI is lines of code. However, you can still use size classes and autolayout in code (and do not need to import extra, unnecessary third-party frameworks like `snapkit`)

Comment: @keith and roboticCat, I have this issue right now and using constraints as the solution is impractical to expect 7Plus sizes to work on a humble SE. Elements really have to be rearranged, or even deleted or set to new layers of subviews to make the app practical for a touch interface.

Comment: It's ok to use different layouts of views, or even different views entirely, for different size classes. `UISplitViewController` is a good example of this.